# Install updates without breaking shell theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, updates, command-line

Recently I installed a copy of Oneiric Ocelot 11.10 on my ThinkPad. Everything went fine, I installed the gnome shell and gnome-tweak-tool to customize everything. I changed the shell theme, the GTK+ theme and the icon set.

After everything fit my needs perfectly, I installed some updates from the update manager (no upgrades, just small updates). I had to restart, and after I restarted, my gnome shell was broken. In tweak-tool, it showed the customized shell as the default one, and my gtk theme was broken as well (it looked like two themes "frankensteined" together...). The bad thing was - I couldn't get things back into the default settings!

So the only thing left was to use the -non broken- unity shell.

What can I do to stop these things from happening? (I mean...sure I could avoid the updates, but that would be kind of stupid, too.)

I only have these PPAs installed:

- ferramroberto-gnome3-oneiric.list (and .save),
- playonlinux.list (and .save)

And how can I fix the broken gnome-shell?

Comment: Do you have any ppa's enabled ?

Comment: yes, I think so...
I didnt change the ppas after install, except I added one or two custom ones (which were necessary for the themes), and I enabled the ppas from canonical partners.

Comment: open a terminal. `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Do you have an entry ricotz-testing-oneiric ? if yes, you should delete that.

Comment: I am not at my computer right now, but I'll give you an answer as soon as I get home!

Comment: nope, just ferramroberto-gnome3-oneiric.list (and .save), and playonlinux.list (and .save)

Comment: could you also please explain, what you mean by : "Installed some updates from the update manager (no upgrades, just small updates)" Did you pick and choose which updates to install or that you just updated using the update manager ? also, please edit your post and add a screenshot, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found my answer - at least for the messed up GTK+ theme.

An application named "unico" has to be installed to activate this theme.

At deviantART (where I found the theme), the following sentence is listed under "known bugs":

> *"Because gnome-shell and gtk3 is still in development there may be a lot of bugs present after each update of the packages gnome-themes-standard, unico engine and gnome-shell."*

I guess I'll just have to stick with the default theme...

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, thinkpad T410,  fixed by uninstalling gnome-shell from oneiric updates 3.2.1 and reverting to 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Shell is provided natively (package `gnome-shell`) in Oneiric, so you don't need to use a PPA to get it, and doing so is not recommended, unless the PPA is providing an alternate version which you know you need.

I recommend removing the [**ferramroberto/gnome3** PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/gnome3), by running these commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ferramroberto/gnome3
```

Check to see if `gnome-shell` is still installed. It should be.

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell
```

If it's not still installed, install it (this will now be from the official repositories):

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

If it cannot find `gnome-shell` to install it, then you probably don't have the Universe repository enabled. To enable it, open the **Software Sources** window (`Edit` > `Software Sources` in the **Software Center**, or `Settings...` in the **Update Manager**, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the command `software-properties-gtk`) and check the box labeled `Community-maintained Open Source software (universe)`. Then click `Close`.

Comment: Hello eliah, you know - out of frustration (customized for hours, then the theme broke...), I deleted the ubuntu partition a few days ago. I will now install it again, the same way I did before. I think ferramrobertos ppa was added because I wanted to install the VLC player. If your advice fixes the gnome-shell (which wasnt really -that- broken, I just couldnt get it back to the default setting), there is still the problem with the GTK+ theme. how would you fix that? I will install 11.10 and get back to you soon :)

Comment: @Niko You don't need any PPA to install `vlc` either (and never have). Do you have specific needs regarding VLC that are not met by the version provided in the official repositories? As for the GTK+ theme, my guess is that the problem is specific to the build of GTK+3 that is provided by the **ferramroberto/gnome3** PPA and that it will go away by itself when you stop using that PPA.

Comment: Hello eliah! Okay, so now I installed everything on the laptop again, and the system really fits my needs now. I updated everything with the update-manager and then started to change the theme again (you know, just to see if it works...). I now have "webupd8team-gnome3-oneiric.list (and .save), and webupd8team-themes-oneiric.list" in my sources.list.d folder. From the first source I got the gnome-shell-extensions, and from the 2nd one I got a theme. So I guess you want me to remove those two ppas to stop everything from breaking again, correct? :) Thanks a lot for your support so far!